# LOAD DATA INFILE PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Good afternoon

I'm trying to use PHP to transfer data from a CSV file into a MySQL Database. The code I have so far is:

```
$insert_query = "
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'sample.csv'
    INTO table tblUncovered
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    (headcode, booked);
    "

if (!mysqli_query($insert_query, $conn)) {
    echo "Can't insert student record : " . mysql_error($conn);
    } 
    else {
    echo "You have successfully insert records into student table";
    }
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working. If I comment out the last bit (If mysql_query onwards) the page will load, albeit do nothing. But when I include those lines, all I get is that 'This page isn't working'.

I've even tried using a file with just two rows and two fields and it won't have it.

Any ideas why?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are not safe and they are deprecated if you are using PHP 5.5+. You should use `mysqli_*` or PDO.

Comment: More than likely you need to supply the full path for the csv file. Check your web server error log.

Comment: is it your server? many hosters deactivate LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE for security reasons. did you try absolute path?

Comment: I see the edit and i don't know if the op is using `mysqli_query` but if so it should be `mysqli_query($conn,$insert_query)`

Comment: Thanks - I checked with my host and they have disabled the LOAD DATA INFILE for security reasons - so I will have to look at how to parse it with PHP.